# I want to count time as code runs and after 5 sec i want to print number which is in loop but why my code is not working for time.time()?

Tags: python-3.x

It takes numbers of range 10000 and in every 5 sec it print the number. I dont know why its not working

```
import time
start=time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    if(int(time.time()-start)==5):
        print('Hello ',i)
        
        time.sleep(3)
        start=time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code locally, and I don't think there's anything wrong with it. The reason you do not see any print is because the whole for loop runs in less than 5 seconds. Please try changing to a bigger value.

It might also help to have another variable equal to the value of the very first `start` value (timeInitial) and then add the following at the end of the code, after the for loop.

```
print (f'Total time: {int(time.time() - timeInitial)}')
```

When having `for i in range(10000):` the value printed is "Total time: 0". Increase the range to `20000000` and I got `Hello 15107775` and `Total time: 9`. Your values may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Just change time.sleep(3) to time.sleep(5) and move it out of the if block

```
import time
start=time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    if(int(time.time()-start)==5):
        print('Hello ',i)
        start=time.time()
    time.sleep(5)
```